# How can i transfer my python program on a website

Tags: python, html, django, web, python-webbrowser

I got a program, written in python, and my mission is to implement this on a website, so other can have access to it. I already tried Django and Flask, but they want me to translate my python code into html. I'm searching for the possibility to Paste my python program into a file which implements the program on a website.

PS: My program includes a user interface and File implements.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, can this answer to your question? https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/169/